# To remove the alphabets and special characters from the floating number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below string in that i have to filter out alphabets and special characters and also i have to remove the dot which is appearing after the decimal point.

```
var number = '1.25eretr6565....$#$%'
number.replace( /[^0-9.]/g, '' );
```

For the above am getting the result as `"1.256565...."`

but the expected result is `1.256565`. Have to remove the dot which is appearing after the decimal point?

Comment: Please show the code with which you're getting `1.256565....`

Comment: i have added that code above with the regex

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
number.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '' ).split(".").filter(item => item !== "").map((item, index) => (index === 0)?item+'.' : item
).join('')
```

Happy to help

Comment: if we add var number = '1.25eretr6...565....$#$%' and am getting  "1.256.565" as an output. In this case expected output is 1.256565

Comment: I have edited the answer as per you requirement. I'll try to make the code better in the mean time

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this :

```
function getNumberValueFromAlphanumeric(number) {
  var numberValue = number.replace( /[^0-9.]/g, '' );
  var valueArray = numberValue.split(".").filter(item => item !== "");
  // extract first value 
  var firstValue = valueArray[0];
  //remove first value from array
  valueArray.shift()
  //create second value
  var secondValue = valueArray.join("");
  var expectedValue = firstValue + "." + secondValue;
  return expectedValue;
}
```

this works for all value that I can think of at this moment
Happy to help